# Why my comments are repeating 3 or 4 times each ?

Tags: php, while-loop, comments

This is just the php code of my comment form and iam not sure if i should use "while" but when i type the code this way i all the comments i have in the DB but each one of them repeats 3 or 4 times ? Where is my mistake ?

```
<div id="comments">
            <?php 
            $post_id = $_GET['post'];
            $q = mysql_query("SELECT comment, author FROM comments WHERE post_id ='$post_id' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
            while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
                ?>

                    Comment: <?php echo $comment['comment']; ?><br /><br />
                     Added from: <?php echo $comment['author']; ?><br />
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is in your `comments` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `JOIN` condition between `comment` and `author` tables and possibly missing the `post` table that has the actual Posts that the comments are on. That's likely the reason why you are getting so many rows.